# Symfony2 prod environment, swiftmailer log

Tags: symfony, production-environment, swiftmailer

I am having problems when I use my Symfony2 project in prod environment. I am getting this log... anyone could help me? In dev environment, everything is ok...

> [2014-06-29 20:12:24] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Twig_Error_Syntax: "An exception has been thrown during the
>   compilation of a template ("There is no "yui_js" filter.") in
>   "AvocodeFormExtensionsBundle::javascripts.html.twig"." at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\UniDocs\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php line
>   564 {"exception":"[object] (Twig_Error_Syntax: An exception has been
>   thrown during the compilation of a template (\"There is no \"yui_js\"
>   filter.\") in \"AvocodeFormExtensionsBundle::javascripts.html.twig\".
>   at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\UniDocs\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php:564,
>   InvalidArgumentException: There is no \"yui_js\" filter. at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\UniDocs\vendor\kriswallsmith\assetic\src\Assetic\FilterManager.php:35)"}
>   []

Comment: Look into this documentation, http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/yuicompressor.html. It looks like you are missing the yui_js file to compress the js files in production mode

Comment: I have added the following to my config.yml file:"{% javascripts '@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/js/*' filter='yui_js' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}". However... it still doesn't work in prod environment. I think the problem may be swiftmailer...

Comment: The log I am getting now is: "[2014-06-30 09:23:57] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /assetic/css/compiled/avocodeformextensions/form-extensions.min_select2_1.css" (from "http://project/web/es/usuario/datos_personales")" at C:\xampp\htdocs\UniDocs\app\cache\prod\classes.php line 1964 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for \"GET /assetic/css/compiled/avocodeformextensions/form-extensions.min_select2_1.css\" (from \"http://project/we...

Comment: Dit you download the yuicompressor to this location:  app/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar and did you add this to your config then? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/yuicompressor.html#configure-the-yui-filters

That should be all to get this working

Comment: I have added the filters in config.yml and downloaded the yuicompressor.jar in app/Resources/java. Do I also have to apply the filters "{% javascripts '@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/js/*' filter='yui_js' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}"? where do I have to add this code?

Comment: Now I am getting different log error: "[2014-06-30 09:57:53] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /assetic/css/compiled/avocodeformextensions/form-extensions.min.css" (from "project/web/backend/")" at C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\cache\prod\classes.php line 1964 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for \"GET /assetic/css/compiled/avocodeformextensions/form-extensions.min.css\" (from \"http://project/web/backend/\") at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\..."